# Benchmarking doom eternal

Tags: performance, doom-eternal

Is there any built-in benchmark in Doom Eternal? I'd like to play with video options to squeeze as much as possible out of my PC and I am looking for a consistent way to measure the performance effects. I didn't find any benchmarking option in menu, maybe something is accessible from the console?

Answer (score 1):

There is a menu option to show performance metrics in the top-right; while in-game, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and go to Settings → Video → Performance Metrics. You can set it to different levels (e.g. Low to just show the frames per second or Ultra-Nightmare to show everything).